# Concatenation needs a "space" in Perl?

Tags: perl

#### Didn't find any explanation from google on the question, although it's possible that I did not use the correct search word.

script1:

```
#!usr/bin/perl
#concatenation2.pl
use warnings;
use strict;
print"Four sevens are",4*7 ,"\n";
print"Four sevens are".4*7 ."\n";
```

script2:

```
#!usr/bin/perl
#concatenation2.pl
use warnings;
use strict;
print"Four sevens are",4*7,"\n";
print"Four sevens are".4*7."\n";
```

The output for script1 is:

```
Four sevens are28
Four sevens are28
```

Okay, so I (learned that) need to have a space before I close the double quote.
However, the output for script2 ends up a error message:

```
string found where operator expected at concatenate2.pl line 6, near "7."\n""
(Missing operator before "\n"?)
syntax error at concatenate2.pl line 6, near "7."\n""
```

Nowhere could I find an explanation why there needs to be a space between numbers and . in script2, while no space is needed between numbers and ,
I am currently relying on google and the free perl books to help me pick up the language. Any help (general guidelines for this kind of nuances) will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: When using print, comma is an equivalent option to period, because print takes a list of arguments. Use concatenation `.` only when you want to coerce a variable into scalar context (comma is list context). For example: `print "The number of elements is: " . @array` as compared to `print "The elements are: ", @array`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`7.` is a number for `perl` lexer, like `3.1415926535`. To avoid confusion, separate the dot from the preceding digit with a space: `"the answer is " . 4*7 . " times more complicated"`.

Comment: As he said :), But be careful, by the same token, .4 is a number for perl, too. But print "Four sevens are" .4*7 ."\n" works. Try putting a comma before the .4 and you get wrong results. My suggestion (for general guidelines) is to put such expressions in parenthesis "(4*7)"

Comment: I up-arrowed Manidip's comment, but want to add my own that *not* separating computations from printed text by parenthesis is *sloppy*. In reality the only place you need to have a space is between the 7 and the `.`--but good programming habits will beat you to a workable solution much faster than the trial and error I used to find out the minimal change.

Comment: thanks a lot, you all. just began learning programming so there are lots of habits that i need to discard or to pick up.

Comment: The reason `"four is ".4` works is that after the closing quote Perl is expecting an operator, not a number.  Therefore, it interprets the `.` as the concatenation operator instead of a decimal point.